# PowerShell: Adding a printer and looping through USB ports to find the first unused one, creating it and assigning to printer

Tags: powershell

So far I have this:

```
$port = Get-PrinterPort -Name USB001
if ($port -eq $null) {
  Add-PrinterPort -Name USB001 -PrinterHostAddress "\\localhost" -PrinterPortType USB  -       ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

$printerParams = @{
  Name = "HP LaserJet MFP M232sdw"
  DriverName = "HP LaserJet MFP M232-M237 PCLm-S"
  Port = $port.Name
  Verbose = $true
}
```

I dont know where to begin to move past looking at USB001. In the end I want this script to find the first unusued USB port and assign that to the printer.
`

-Thank you

I feel like I need to add an else clause but im not sure where to begin. This is part of a major project for me at a new job so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Following will give all USB devices.  Filter as needed : gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)}

Comment: This may work : gwmi Win32_USBControllerDevice |%{[wmi]($_.Dependent)}| Where-Object {($_.Description -like "*Printer*")}

Comment: `-PrinterPortType` is not valid syntax. Where did this script come from? Are you trying to add this specific printer to multiple computers?

Comment: Yeah Im trying to add this specific printer on multiple computers. Same model number and driver set

Comment: @anothervictimofthemouse I got it from chatgpt. I wasnt sure to begin with in the first place.

Comment: @ITnoob can you use a GPO?